# Access Logs inside k8 pods

Tags: kubernetes

We have a k8 cluster. I am trying to access logs from inside and `kubectl` won't work inside. Where would be the logs stored in k8? 
We do not have systemd and found in the docs that:

```
 If systemd is not present, they write to .log files in the /var/log directory. System components inside containers always write to the /var/log directory, bypassing the default logging mechanism.
```

But I could not find any logs in here. So how can I get access to these logs which I would get by `kubectl logs`  from inside the pod?
How does default logging work in k8 without any logging mechanism setup?

PS: I did go through other similar posts and had no luck with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application does not log to a file, it may log to `stdout` sometimes (which `kubectl logs <pod name>` should also show).

1. You can try `docker logs <name or ID of the container`
2. If the `/var/log` directory does not persist in a volume mounted in the container, it will be lost when the pod restarts or moves in the cluster as the `/var/log` directory will be ephemeral. Check if the pod has restarted or moved in the cluster.
3. Find if the pod uses any volumes for persistent storage of `/var/log` by doing:

   ```
   kubectl get <pod name> -o yaml | grep -i volume
   kubectl get persistentvolumes --all-namespaces
   kubectl get persistentvolumeclaims --all-namespaces
   ```

Comment: I can't see any logs in /var/log. And pod is not using any volumes for persistent storage. kubectl get <pod name> -o yaml | grep -i volume , it doesnt show anything.

Comment: @AkhilanandBenkalVenkanna Upvote and accept my answer if you think it is useful so that others know this is the right answer, thanks! If no logs are found on disk, volume or stdout, I think it is an application issue for not logging properly.

Comment: I can see the logs with kubectl logs which i assume indicates the logs are geing written to stdout . But my question seems to be unanswered as my pod is not using any volume . So my naive question is kubectl must be fetching these logs from somewhere. I just wanted to know from where?

Comment: `kubectl logs` shows the applications's output on `stdout` and/or `stderr`. If an app writes to stdout, it is not stored on the disk unless the application is designed to do so (i.e., to specifically copy stdout onto a file on disk/volume).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the logs you want to access available via `kubectl logs` then it means they are ultimately output to stdout or stderr. Docker and kubelet work on top of standard outputs, processing these logs in their own fashion (ie. by logging plugins). When your process throws something to sdtout, it is obviously not stored anywhere on the local filesystem of the container.

That said, you can configure your app to log to files, but mind that you need to handle logrotation, cleanup etc. or your container will perpetualy grow. If you can't have both in parallel, you do loose them from docker/kubernetes logs though, which is not so nice. If that is the case, you can have a process in a sidecar that reads logfiles from mounted volume and sends them to stdout/stderr.

The real question is why do you need to access logs inside POD. Knowing that maybe there is a better way to achieve what you need (ie. pipe them first via some parser process).

Comment: So you are trying to tell that by default , the logs that are thrown out STDOUT and STDERR and are not stored inside the pods or any other place inside the k8 cluster?

Comment: And the reason why I need to see logs inside my pod is to create a script so that liveness probe can kick in whenever we see errors or containers get killed as we still do not have an HTTP endpoint for it.

Comment: "inside k8s cluster" is a broad and fuzzy concept - ie. is EFK deployed and integrated on cluster level inside or not? anyway, as it comes to pure pod related part, yes, that is what I'm saying. One of the things you might do is writing a tiny control program, that will fork to run your software and capture/pipe stdout of child process to container stdout meanwhile analysing it as you would analyze log file stream. But really the best architecture would be to support http endpoints in your app to expose . something like ie :8080/ready :8080/metrics etc.

Comment: Yes thats what the long term goal is to.. meanwhile i was trying to find a way to access these logs without using kubectl inside the pod.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that the application just logs in a file/directory inside the container.

Could you use

`kubectl exec -it <podname>  bash`

or

`kubectl exec -it <podname>  sh`

to enter the container/pod and check the logs inside the container.

Comment: That's what my question is that I am not able to find the logs inside the pod.